# prawn - bounds don't stick to the edges

Tags: ruby, prawn

I generate PDFs based on some templates with ruby pdf libary - prawn. 
My script simply adds a signature at the top of the first template page.

I noticed that when I open a template and do stroke_bounds sometimes they don't stick to the edges of the page - so the signature has wrong position (as it depends on bounds).

Is there a way to normalize it? Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, there is a default margin (0.5 inch). But you can change it with the `:margin` option. (`:left_margin, :right_margin,
:top_margin, :bottom_margin`). Hope that this was useful.

Comment: As I remember it did the trick but it's not an universal solution...
I have to set new margins as I change template.